# regular expression asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I trying to improve a textbox that filters a gridview, by implementing an enhanced textbox that can identify AND, OR, NOT operators by searching for this keywords in the string the user inputs in the textbox.

I am trying to do a regular expression to group the results but I'm not very good at this and I am failing to get what I want.

An example of what I want is as follows:

```
string = "build1 and build2 and build3 or build4 or not build5 and not build6"
```

results in a split mode:

- build1 and
- build2 and
- build3 or
- build4 or not
- build5 and not
- build6

This is because then I will take the first for example and replace with

```
SomeTable.Name_Of_Build = 'build1' AND
```

`SomeTable.Name_Of_Build = 'build2' AND` .... so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might recommend that instead of using a regular expression to group the results you do something like this. I think it would be more robust than trying to guess at the right regex.

```
string filter = "build1 and buil2 and build3 or build4 or not build5"
list<string> filterTokens = filter.Split(new char[] {' '})

string gridViewFilter = "";    
bool notEqual = false;

foreach(string token in filterTokens)
{
   if(token == "and")
   {
      gridViewFilter += "and"
   }
   else if(token == "or")
   {
     gridViewFilter += "or"
   }
   else if(token == "not")
   {
      notEqual = true;
   }
   else if(notEqual)
   {
      gridViewFilter += "SomeTable.Name_Of_Build <> '" + token + "'";
      notEqual = false;
   }
   else
   {
      gridViewFilter += "SomeTable.Name_Of_Build <> '" + token + "'";
   }
}
```

Also, if you really want to implement a robust and full featured sort you need to look into using [Reverse Polish Notation (RPN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). It would allow you to handle parentheses and order of operations. An RPN implementation would look something like this.

```
private bool CheckForFilterMatch(string filter, List<string> values, bool exactMatch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        values[i] = values[i].ToLower();
    }

    if (filter.Trim() == "")
    {
        return true;
    }

    List<string> rpn = GetPostFixNotation(filter);

    Stack<bool> output = new Stack<bool>();

    foreach (string token in rpn)
    {
        if (IsValue(token))
        {
            bool isMatch;
            if (exactMatch)
            {
                isMatch = values.Contains(token.ToLower());
            }
            else
            {
                isMatch = false;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    isMatch = (value.IndexOf(token.ToLower()) != -1);

                    if (isMatch) break;
                }
            }

            output.Push(isMatch);
        }
        else if (IsOperator(token))
        {
            bool operand1 = output.Pop();
            bool operand2 = output.Pop();

            if (token == "&")
            {
                output.Push(operand1 && operand2);
            }
            if (token == "|")
            {
                output.Push(operand1 || operand2);
            }
        }
    }

    return output.Pop();
}


public  List<string> GetPostFixNotation(string filter)
{
    if (filter == "")
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    List<string> postFixNotation = new List<string>();

    Queue<string> output = new Queue<string>();
    Stack<string> operators = new Stack<string>();

    List<string> parsedFilter = ParseFilterTokens(filter);

    foreach (string token in parsedFilter)
    {
        if (IsValue(token))
        {
            output.Enqueue(token);
        }
        else if (IsOperatorNoParenth(token))
        {
            while (operators.Count > 0 && IsOperatorNoParenth(operators.Peek()))
            {
                if ((operators.Count > 0 && (Precedence(token) <= Precedence(operators.Peek()))))
                {
                    string operatorToReturn = operators.Pop();
                    output.Enqueue(operatorToReturn);
                }
                else break;
            }

            operators.Push(token);
        }
        else if (token == "(")
        {
            operators.Push(token);
        }
        else if (token == ")")
        {
            while (operators.Count > 0 && operators.Peek() != "(")
            {
                output.Enqueue(operators.Pop());
            }
            operators.Pop();
        }
    }

    while (operators.Count > 0)
    {
        output.Enqueue(operators.Pop());
    }

    while (output.Count > 0)
    {
        postFixNotation.Add(output.Dequeue());
    }

    return postFixNotation;

}
```

Comment: This is a wonderful solution as well, but I think with the first example you put here I can also respect parentheses and order of operations. I appreciate a lot your point of view as well!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

\w+(\sand\snot|\sor\snot|\sand|\sor|$)

Comment: wow this one is great man, thanks a lot! It also respects if I add "()" to the string. But the thing is that I want to learn so, what does the $ means?
Also I made a little change and have my expression like this: (\w+\sand\snot|\w+\sor\snot|\w+\sand|\w+\sor|$)

Comment: $ matches the end of the string. The () enclose match choices separated by |. The change you made should work, but is a little wasteful as you are including \w+ (match any character) in each or statement, also you haven't included it before the $ so the last match is missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex out:

> (build[^b]+)

Comment: thanx for the answer but I guess i did not make my self clear. the build's words are just examples, what's important for me is the AND, OR, NOT inside the string